# Sum all numbers prepended to text that matches a search string

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have cells that contain multiple strings delimited by commas.

Each string is comprised of the following 3 elements joined together:

1. A `number`
2. An `x`
3. A `substring`

For example, `1xExample`, `2xExample`, `2xAnotherExample`, `5xThirdExample`, etc.

I want to add the `number` from each string that contains a particular `substring`.

Sample Data

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| **1** | 1xExample, 2xAnotherExample, 5xThirdExample |
| **2** | 1xAnotherExample, 3xThirdExample, 2xExampleFour |

For example, using the sample data above, if the `substring` I'm trying to match is `AnotherExample` then the formula would return `3`. `AnotherExample` appears once in `A1` preceded by a `2` and it also appears once in `A2` preceded by a `1`.  So adding the `numbers` from those two  strings gives `2+1=3`.

I've tried a few different things and the closest I can get is a formula which takes all numbers in the cell and adds them together instead of taking a specific number.

Is there a way for a formula to find all the strings that contain a `substring` and then take the `number` from each of those strings and add them together?

Comment: Please share a link to a sample spreadsheet with *realistic* data in it (at least five rows), along with the *hand-entered* results that you'd like to see a formula produce for that sample set. The closer to your real data you can make the sample data, the better.

Comment: Hi and welcome to WebApps. _Such as: Finding "xAnotherExample" in Cell C1..._ - that sounds like a good approach. What result did you get when you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

Use `regexextract()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  sum( 
    iferror( 
      regexextract(A2:A, "(\d+)xAnotherExample") + 0 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```